# React-Redux: How do I set the initial state from the response of an asynchronous AJAX call?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How to setState() the response received from an AJAX Request so that I can display them in the page?

```
 constructor(props)
 {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        first_name: '',
        middle_name: '',
        country: '',
        country_code: '',
        mobile_number: '',
        gender: ''
    }
 }

componentDidMount()
{
    store.dispatch(getUserProfile())
    .then(() => {
        const user = this.props.userProfile.userProfile && this.props.userProfile.userProfile.data.data;
        this.setState({
          email: user.email,
          first_name: user.first_name
        });

    })
}

render()
{
    return (
       <div className="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email*</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email || ''}/>
       </div>

        <div className="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label htmlFor="email">First Name*</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.first_name || ''}/>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Apparently, I can't use .then() with store.dispatch method.

> Uncaught TypeError: _store2.default.dispatch(...).then is not a function

**`getUserProfile() action function`**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getUserProfile()
{
    return function(dispatch)
    {

        dispatch(userProfileSuccess(false));
        dispatch(userProfileError(null));

        const request = axios
        ({
            url: "http://testapi/auth/v1/user/details",
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            }
        })

        .then(function(response) { dispatch(userProfileSuccess(response)); })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        });

        return {
            type: 'USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS',
            payload: request
        }

    };

}

function userProfileSuccess(userProfile)
{
    return {
        type: 'USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS',
        userProfile: userProfile
    };
}
function userProfileError(userProfileError)
{
    return {
        type: 'USER_PROFILE_ERROR',
        userProfileError: userProfileError
    };
}

export default getUserProfile;
```

In the AJAX call, I tried:

```
.then(function(response) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            dispatch(userProfileSuccess(response));
            resolve();
        });

    })
```

but the console reports the same error.

Is there a callback that I can pass to `store.dispatch`? What is the correct approach to this?

Comment: You can call getUserProfile() directly by passing dispatch function as an argument to it. Then this function will internally call api and when result is available, it will update the reducer by dispatching action. Then all you have to do is connect you component with redux store by mapStateToProps function

Comment: Can you add the code for getUserProfile

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks a lot for the time.

Comment: you can use the [connect helper](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) and import your action file in your component this basically will allow you to call your action function as `this.props.your_action_funtion()`

Comment: good info, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using redux then your redux store should keep track about when the api call is in progress or has completed or caught some error. So instead of passing any callback or promise, you should dispatch an action for each event like processing, success, error etc (which you are already doing in getprofile function). Though i would say you nicely distinguish between process, success, error. For example you getprofile method should roughly look like this

```js
export function getUserProfile() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(userProfileProcessing())

        const request = axios({
            url: "http://testapi/auth/v1/user/details",
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
            },
        })

        .then(function (response) {
            dispatch(userProfileSuccess(response))
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            dispatch(userProfileError(response))
            console.log(error)
        });
    };
}
```

It is just what i prefer. If you want it your way, that is also fine.

Now everytime you dispatch any action, redux will update the reducer state. So thats the place where you can set/reset some flag to make the component aware of what is going on with api call. So your reducer might look like this:

```js
// getUserProfileReducer.js

userProfileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USER_PROFILE_PROCESSING':
            return {
                ...state,
                processing: true,
                success: false,
                fail: false,
                userProfile: null,
            }
        case 'USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                processing: false,
                success: true,
                fail: false,
                userProfile: action.userProfile,
            }
        case 'USER_PROFILE_Error':
            return {
                ...state,
                processing: false,
                success: false,
                fail: true,
                userProfile: null,
            }
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is to access this state from you component so that you can take necessary action according to that. For that you can user mapStateToProps function which convert the redux state to prop of the component.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        first_name: '',
        middle_name: '',
        country: '',
        country_code: '',
        mobile_number: '',
        gender: '',
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.userProfileStatus.success) {
        // The success flag is true so set the state
        const user = newProps.userProfileStatus
        this.setState({
            email: user.email,
            first_name: user.first_name,
        })
    }
    else if (newProps.userProfileStatus.processing) {
        // Api call is in progress so do action according to that like show loader etc.
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(getUserProfile())
}

render() {
    return (
        ...
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userProfileStatus: state.userProfileReducer,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Sharma. Your explanation is very helpful. I see that I need to take some time to re-understand the whole react-redux workflow. I also need to create additional states in the reducer to track the progress of API calls and also make use of `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Hi, Prakash! What would `userProfileProcessing()` in the getUserProfile() action look like?

Comment: userProfileProcessing(), userProfileSuccess(), userProfileFail() are action creators which will return an object. That returned object will be passed as "action" argument to reducer by redux internally. If you look at the reducer in this answer, we are doing switch case on  action.type. So the object returned by those function must have at least a type property to identify what kind of action dispatched.

Comment: It will be same as the two functions at the bottom of your getUserProfile() function code snippet in question.

Comment: That's helpful explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a callback in componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount()
{
    store.dispatch(getUserProfile(), () => {
        const user = this.props.userProfile.userProfile && this.props.userProfile.userProfile.data.data;
        this.setState({
          email: user.email,
          first_name: user.first_name
        });

    })
}
```

This may not run exactly same, I just want to give you an idea how to add callback using arrow function so that you don't need to use then.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Redux stores the state in the Redux store, separately from the React component state (think setState). You are almost there. What you need to do is guide the result data from the async dispatch to the redux store and then to your local component state. Steps 3 and 4 below.

1. Dispatch an async action to fetch the data.
2. Dispatch an action from within the promise to populate the redux state.
3. Write a [reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) that intercepts the action and populates the redux state.
4. [Connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) your local component state with the redux state by using the `connect` function.

Comment: That's good information; much obliged. I get them all except step 2.

Here's how I understand the workflow.

`1.` Create the action
`1.` Create reducer to handle response or error based on the action
`3.` Create mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions.
`4.` Use connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) to connect actions and states to the component.

Would you explain further how, in a component function do I perform an operation after the asynchronous `this.props.doThisAction()`  is complete?